# Is there anyway you can sort by keys to use atStart and atEnd for Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

My first attempt was to Query Firebase using an atStart and endTime, however, I feel like my case is a bit different as the "keys" for my database is the epoch time in which data is being sent over, and the value is an accelerometer value. Is there anyway I could be able to set a start and end time for a specific epoch interval to retrieve data? I want to be able to only retrieve data from today’s date of a start time of 00:00:00 and end date of 23:59:59.

My first attempt was to create calendar instances such as

(Some pseucode below, I broke my program and had to revert to my old GitHub commit)

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.IMarker;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.Legend;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.XAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.YAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.datasets.ILineDataSet;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class Homepage extends AppCompatActivity{

    private LineChart chart;
    private FirebaseUser user;
    private DatabaseReference reference;
    private String userID;
    private TextView tvTitle;
    long reference_timestamp;

    ArrayList<Long> acTime = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Long> newAcTime = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Long> acValues = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Entry> result = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage);

        tvTitle = findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        chart = findViewById(R.id.petChart);
        chart.setDragEnabled(true);
        chart.setScaleEnabled(true);

        Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        c1.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        c1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        c1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        c1.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);

        Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        c2.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 59);
        c2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
        c2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
        c2.set(Calendar.HOUR, 23);

        long startTime = c1.getTimeInMillis()/1000;
        long endTime = c2.getTimeInMillis()/1000;

        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        userID = user.getUid();
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users/" + userID);
        Query query = reference.orderByKey().startAt(String.valueOf(startTime)).endAt(String.valueOf(endTime));

        System.out.println("Printing reference:" + reference);

        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                DataSnapshot acSnapshot = dataSnapshot.child("Data");

                System.out.println("getting accelerometer values");
                for (DataSnapshot valueSnapshot : acSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    acValues.add(Long.parseLong((valueSnapshot.getValue(String.class))));
                    acTime.add(Long.parseLong((valueSnapshot.getKey())));
                }

                long temp_time;
                for (int i = 0; i < acTime.size(); i++)
                {
                    reference_timestamp = acTime.get(0);
                    System.out.println("Printing acTime.get(0):" + acTime.get(0));
                    temp_time = acTime.get(i) - reference_timestamp;
                    System.out.println("Printing temp_time:" + temp_time);
                    newAcTime.add(temp_time);
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < newAcTime.size(); i++)
                {
                    System.out.println(newAcTime.get(i));
                }

                System.out.println("setting results array");
                for (int i = 0; i < acTime.size(); i++)
                {
                    result.add(new Entry(newAcTime.get(i), acValues.get(i)));
                }

                System.out.println("setting dataset");

                Date date = new Date(acTime.get(0)*1000);
                DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy");
                String formatted = format.format(date);

                tvTitle.setText("Accelerometer Data for " + formatted);




                LineDataSet set1 = new LineDataSet(result, "Magnitude of Accelerometer Data");

                chart.setTouchEnabled(true);
                chart.setDragEnabled(true);
                chart.setScaleEnabled(true);
                chart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
                chart.setHighlightPerDragEnabled(true);

                chart.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                chart.setViewPortOffsets(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);


                set1.setDrawValues(false);
                set1.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
                set1.setColor(Color.rgb(0,0,165));
                set1.setLineWidth(1.5f);
                set1.setDrawCircles(true);

                System.out.println("creating arraylist for datasets");
                ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();

                System.out.println("adding dataset to set1");
                dataSets.add(set1);

                System.out.println("creating LineData data2 for datasets");
                LineData data2 = new LineData(dataSets);



                System.out.println("setting the data");
                chart.setData(data2);


                chart.getDescription().setText("");
                IMarker marker = new YourMarkerView(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.marker, reference_timestamp);
                chart.setMarker(marker);

                Legend l = chart.getLegend();

                l.setForm(Legend.LegendForm.LINE);
                l.setVerticalAlignment(Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.TOP);
                l.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
                l.setOrientation(Legend.LegendOrientation.HORIZONTAL);
                l.setDrawInside(false);


                XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
                xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM_INSIDE);
                xAxis.setTextSize(16f);
                xAxis.setValueFormatter(new XAxisValueFormatter(reference_timestamp));
//                xAxis.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
//                xAxis.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 192, 56));
                xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);
                xAxis.setLabelCount(3);
                xAxis.setCenterAxisLabels(true);


                YAxis leftAxis = chart.getAxisLeft();
                leftAxis.setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.INSIDE_CHART);
                leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
                leftAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
                leftAxis.setLabelCount(3);
                leftAxis.setTextSize(16f);
                leftAxis.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                YAxis rightAxis = chart.getAxisRight();
                rightAxis.setEnabled(false);

                System.out.println("notifying data sets changed");
                chart.notifyDataSetChanged();

                System.out.println("invalidate");
                chart.invalidate();
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                throw databaseError.toException();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Error message when I try to graph:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 5632
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.Homepage}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must use startAt(String value), endAt(String value) or equalTo(String value) in combination with orderByKey(). Other type of values or using the version with 2 parameters is not supported
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5456)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5362)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ClientTransactionHandler.executeTransaction(ClientTransactionHandler.java:58)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityLocally(ActivityThread.java:5415)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3300(ActivityThread.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2076)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must use startAt(String value), endAt(String value) or equalTo(String value) in combination with orderByKey(). Other type of values or using the version with 2 parameters is not supported
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query.validateQueryEndpoints(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:92)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query.startAt(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:364)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query.startAt(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:335)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query.startAt(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:292)
        at com.example.myapplication.Homepage.onCreate(Homepage.java:77)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5456) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5362) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ClientTransactionHandler.executeTransaction(ClientTransactionHandler.java:58) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityLocally(ActivityThread.java:5415) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3300(ActivityThread.java:237) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2076) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5632 SIG: 9
```

UPDATE:
If I try to convert the longs to Strings, I get this error...

```
        Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        c1.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        c1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        c1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        c1.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);

        Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        c2.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 59);
        c2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
        c2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
        c2.set(Calendar.HOUR, 23);

        long startTime = c1.getTimeInMillis()/1000;
        long endTime = c2.getTimeInMillis()/1000;

        String start = Long.toString(startTime);
        String end = Long.toString(endTime);

        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        userID = user.getUid();
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users/" + userID);
        Query query = reference.orderByKey().startAt(start).endAt(end);
```

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 7032
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.example.myapplication.Homepage$1.onDataChange(Homepage.java:119)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

[image: Sample database]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The approach and structure of the query look fine at first glance. What problem do you have in implement the rest of this code?

Comment: Hello, @FrankvanPuffelen, I have added the code and the error that I get. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong, thank you!

Comment: Should I read the data in differently? Do you think I’m having trouble because of how I set the epoch time as the key? @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is pretty clear:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must use startAt(String value), endAt(String value) or equalTo(String value) in combination with orderByKey(). Other type of values or using the version with 2 parameters is not supported

Keys in Firebase Realtime Database are always string values, even when they may look like numbers at first glance. So you need to pass string values to `startAt()` and `endAt()` too. A simple way to do that would be:

```
reference.orderByKey().startAt(String.valueOf(startTime)).endAt(String.valueOf(endTime))
```

Comment: Hi! I tried doing that, and I have been met with this exception. I have updated my code to properly reflect what I have currently in my initial post. Thank you for all of the help thus far!

Comment: I think I found the problem... I don't seem to be loading anything into my ArrayLists. Their size is 0.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to remove the error message that I provided an explanation of. That makes it incomprehensible for users who stumble upon this in the guture.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have included the original error.

Comment: Since this answer solves the exception you posted, it is custom to accept it, try to solve the next problem on your own (there are *a lot* of questions about that error message already), and post a new question with a new [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you get stuck again.